# Riemann Zeta - Euler product convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, euler-product

I'm fascinated by the Riemann Zeta hypothesis - I haven't yet taken a course in complex analysis but I'm curious what this sentence means on Wikipedia:

> The convergence of the Euler product shows that ζ(s) has no zeros in
>   this region, as none of the factors have zeros.

I'm wondering if a) the convergence of the Euler product comes purely from the fact that the p-series diverges when the exponent is greater than 1?
b) What the sentence from Wikipedia is essentially saying - I'm not understanding what factors are being referred to or how the convergence shows that the Zeta function has no zeroes for $\Re(s) > 1$.

Edit: I was looking over [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1097980/268374) answer and it seems to be similar, but how do we know that, as this author wrote, $(1-p^{-s})^{-1}\neq 0$ for all primes $p$? Can't it converge to 0, meaning that $(1-p^{-s})^{-1} = 0$ for at least one prime $p$?

Comment: The idea is that $\zeta(s) =\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} = \exp(F(s))$ where $F(s) = -\sum_p \log(1-p^{-s}) = \sum_{p^k} \frac{p^{-sk}}{k}$ is analytic on $\Re(s) > 1$, thus $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros there.

Comment: $(1-p^{-s})^{-1}$ is between $1$ and $2$ for every real positive $p$.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. So like here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1097980/268374, why do we know $(1-p^{-s})^{-1}\neq 0$ for all primes $p$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-x} = 0$ occurs only when $|x| = \infty$. Here it means $|p^{-s}| = \infty$ ie. $\Re(s) = -\infty$

Comment: Also note that when $s < 0$ : $\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}} = 0$ (the product is said to *diverge* to $0$). That's why it is important to restrict to $\Re(s) > 1$, where we have the equality $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s} = \prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}$.

Comment: @user1952009 oh yeah, so to make sure I'm understanding correctly: because the product converges to 0 if and only if one of the factors is 0, and from what you said, it cannot have a factor in this case equaling 0. But how does this align with the wikipedia statement that "The convergence of the Euler product shows that ζ(s) has no zeros in this region, as none of the factors have zeros."

Comment: That's what I said : here the product converges and its factor are non-zero for $\Re(s) > 1$ really means that $-\sum_p  \log(1-p^{-s}) = \log(\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}})=\log \zeta(s)$ is analytic for $\Re(s) > 1$.

Comment: Ah okay thank you, now when we say "The convergence of the Euler product", it's really the fact that the Euler product converges to a *non-zero* value, correct? Because if it converged to 0, then at least one of the factors must be 0.

Comment: @user1952009, and so the convergent value of the Euler product due to the identity is the same as the zeta function, and so "the convergence of the euler product" converges to a value necessarily greater than 0 shows that the Zeta function does not have roots when $\Re(s)>1$? If this is the case, then my question is fully answered.